# The tags [path-finding] and [shortest-path] are oddly separate

Tags: discussion, tags

So I've been taking a look at the tags [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) and [shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path), trying to figure out what's different between them. The tags seem like they cover a really similar area to me, as evidenced by their tag wikis. The [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) wiki reads:

> Pathfinding generally refers to the problem of finding the shortest route between two points, subject to any obstacles. Pathfinding has application in a wide range of areas including robotics and game development. Algorithms for pathfinding tend to be closely related to graph and tree search algorithms.

[shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path), on the other hand, has this to say about itself:

> Shortest path problems are problems addressing finding the shortest path from a single source to a target source, usually in a graph.

So not exactly the same, but there is a fair bit of overlap. The interesting bit is that the tags themselves barely overlap. A quick search shows 29 questions tagged with both [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) and [shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path). One tag that I've found between them with a lot of overlap so far is the tag [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), tagged 350 times together with [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) and 614 times together with [shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path)

Another interesting thing to note is that [a-star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star) comes up a *lot* on [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding), but not all that much on [shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path).

I have a theory about why this is: [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) seems to get used a lot by people making games, a lot of which use A* for their path finding, and also by people studying path finding/artificial intelligence. [shortest-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path) seems to be used more by people asking questions about specific shortest path algorithms.

So, I'm wondering how this overlap in area but not in tags affects people's ability to answer questions. Should the tags be synonymised? Any other ideas about why this odd split might have happened in the first place? Or maybe they do mean vastly different things, and the tag wikis just need to be updated? Any and all opinions are welcome.

Comment: What am I to take away from the low amount of activity? Do people simply not care, or does nobody have an answer? I am loath to ask another question on the topic.